# Alternative lenses for 450d basic 18-55mm lens

Tags: lens

I have Canon EOS 450d camera that I bought about 7 years ago and till now I have shot for about 15k photos. Lately appeared problems taking shots and when I pushed the button, nothing happened. I thought that camera is damaged but then I understood that the lens has some problems and after testing it by switching MF mode to AF, it worked so the lens doesn't work in MF mode. So, I need to repair it but I think that at this time I will search for a new lens, but I would love to get a better one compared to the basic lens.

How do I decide on a specific lens to fit my needs and budget? Mostly I shoot landscapes, family (outdoor/indoor), activities. Budget - around about 100 euros.

Comment: Before posting this question, did you try searching this website for similar questions?

Comment: Yes, I did, but decided to ask to get more information for my situation.

Comment: Your question is liable to get closed as asking for a product recommendation--something we don't do here on photo.SE, because we're trying to build Q&As that are useful into the future for a relatively wide audience.  You may want to reword it more along the lines of "how do I choose...?" rather than "what do I buy?"  Also, when asking for this type of recommendation (elsewhere), you should state what/how you shoot, what it is you want to improve, _and what your budget is_. Otherwise, some joker's going to tell you to get a $3k L lens. ;)

Comment: €100 is an unrealistically low budget, unless you get lucky on the second-hand market.

Comment: Your question does not seem to make sense to me. You state in your question that the lens works well in AF mode but not MF mode. That does not seem possible. Before you spend money on a new lens you should try another lens on your camera.

Comment: Does not work in **MF** mode... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify what you mean by "better".

The kit lens is actually  a pretty good lens in absolute terms.  It's pretty sharp, has decent optical characteristics and a useful zoom range.  It's also relatively light and small by lens standards.

You've use one for 7 years without feeling the need t change lens, so perhaps you should take the cheap option of a new or used kit lens as a replacement ?

If you're considering other options you might consider one of the 18-135mm models, which will provide more reach and are also optically good.  The 50mm f1.8 option has been explained.  Those are the two I'd recommend for someone who seems not to have had any issue with the kit lens until it mechanically failed.  Look for used models in dealers which give some kind of warranty.

I'd also suggest you check that kit lens carefully.  It could be as simple as dirt on a connector.  Ask a friend or a shop to try it on their camera.

Comment: +1 for "The kit lens is actually a pretty good lens in absolute terms."

Answer (score 3):

**Your budget is too low to upgrade.**  You really only have two choices at that price point, and that would be another 18-55 kit lens, or the EF 50mm f/1.8 II. Maybe the updated EF 50 f/1.8 STM.  (Yongnuo's 35mm f/2 and 50/1.8 are also in the budget, but, well, you get what you pay for). And a 50/1.8 is a distinctly different type of lens, and cannot do everything the 18-55 can do. It will be faster and likely sharper, but it doesn't zoom, so framing versatility really kinda sucks (prepare to run around a lot), and on a crop body like the 450D, a 50mm lens is a short telephoto. Great for portraits, not so great for wide angle landscape usage.

If you want better, you have to pay to get it.  In Canon's estimate, US$300 is "low cost" for a lens, "midrange cost" is closer to US$600, and "expensive" starts at US$1000 and goes upwards from there. Yeah, not reality, but that's kind of how it pans out.  $100 for a new "better" lens is having champagne tastes on a beer budget.

Answer (score 0):

The *basic 18-55mm kit lens* supplied with your EOS 450D has been supplanted by several newer lenses in the 18-55mm lineup. The EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS, IS II, or IS STM versions have significantly better optical quality than the EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 II that was standard with the 450D. With your budget you are fairly limited, but you should be able to find one of these later lenses on the used market in good condition well within that budget. You might also consider the EF-S 15-85mm f/3.5-5.6 IS if you can find a used one within your budget. Be wary of the EF-S 17-85 f/4-5.6 IS on the used market as it is not quite as good optically and also has a known issue with premature wear of one of the internal ribbon cables that can lead to early failure.

Comment: OTOH, an EF-S 15-85 on the used market is around $400-$500, while a used EF-S 17-85 is $100-$200. StephenG's 18-135 suggestion might actually be the most reasonable "upgrade", as that can be found used for around $200 but is a later design than the supplanted 17-85 and 28-135.

Comment: I didn't realize used EF-S 15-85s were so pricey. I also didn't realize a Euro was no longer exchanging for about $1.40-1.50 in U.S. Dollars. *Ouch*. The 15-85s are optically better lenses than either the 17-85 or 18-135 even apart from the reliability issues of the 17-85. And I think comparing eBay prices for the 18-135 to B&H/Adorama/KEH/etc prices for the others is a little bit apples to oranges. You can get a used 15-85 on eBay for $380. Still a bit more than the OPs budget, but then everything but a 50/1.8 is. Even an EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS is going to run $125+.